# A way to do autoregressive forecast using ARIMA

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels, arima, sarimax

I have an ARMAX model trained on a train dataset as follows:

```
train_size = len(y) - 50
train_y, test_y = y['ObservedValue'][:train_size], y['ObservedValue'][train_size:]
train_x, test_x = x['ObservedValue'][:train_size], x['ObservedValue'][train_size:]

# Fit ARMAX model on the training set
model = SARIMAX(train_y, exog=train_x, order=order)
results = model.fit()
```

My case is as follows: For the last `50` observations of my dataset i suppose I have the exogenous variable foe each time step by I am able to get the `y` variable for time step `t` with one lag delay.
What I mean is my testing should be something like:

- I am at time-step `t`
- I want to predict `y(t+1)`
- I have the exogenous variable at `t`, `e(t)`
- The value of `y(t)` will be available at `t+1` (one lag delay) so right now i have `y(t-1)`.

From the information above I can and should use y(t-1) to predict y(t+1).
However, stats model arima only provides:

`results.get_prediction(start = .., end = .., exog = test_x)`

Which I suppose uses previous predictions from test set to predict forthcoming values.
How can i Integrate `y(t-1)` in this approach?